# Kurukulla : The Hindu Version

Tags: devi

I would like to know if possible, the real story viz Hindu Version of Kurukulla according to the Veda texts.

Comment: Mahayogi Satyendranath, who is still alive and roams freely in the snow-capped mountains of the Himalayas barefoot and without cloth worships devi Kurukulla. She is his kula devi. He is the Pithadhish of Kulantak Peeth situated in Himachal Pradesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ancient times shiva created 5 kinds of tantra,Viz.saivasiddhanta,garuda,bhuta,vama,bhairava.Kurukulla is a goddesss of garuda tantra.Her origin is hindu but letter accepted as an buddhist deity.she is a snake goddess.
Vedas knows a goddess Sarparajni but there is heardly any connection between them.